# MySQL syntax for JOIN depending on condition

Tags: mysql, join, if-statement

What would be a syntax of the following query:

Get all columns from Table1 and JOIN Table2 if matching reference (Table1ID) exists, otherwise JOIN Table3.

Simplified DB structure is more or less as below

```
 Table1
 ID     Type
 1      std

 Table2
 ID     Table1ID    Title    Language
 1      1           Test     en

 Table3
 ID     Table1ID    Title    Language     Flag
 1      1           Other    en           1
```

Also, I now realized that Table3 will have multiple entries that refer to single Table1.id. How to limit it to return only the latest entry (with highest id) for every result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want an entire separate set of columns for each join, this may be what you're looking for:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     (     
         SELECT    a.ID AS Table1ID, a.Type, b.ID, b.Title, b.Language, NULL AS Flag
         FROM      Table1 a
         JOIN      Table2 b ON a.ID = b.Table1ID

         UNION ALL

         SELECT    a.ID, a.Type, c.ID, c.Title, c.Language, c.Flag
         FROM      Table1 a
         LEFT JOIN Table2 b ON a.ID = b.Table1ID
         JOIN      Table3 c ON a.ID = c.Table1ID
         JOIN      (
                   SELECT   MAX(id) AS maxid
                   FROM     Table3
                   GROUP BY Table1ID
                   ) d ON c.ID = d.maxid
         WHERE     b.ID IS NULL
         ) a
ORDER BY a.Table1ID
```

---

[*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52f1d/5/0)

Comment: Thanks... I know realize, Table3 will have multiple entries that refer to the same table1.id. How can I take the most recent one (highest table1.id for every result)?

Comment: thanks.. last thing, how to include order by in the query, let say order by Table1.id desc

Comment: @vault-boy, see updated solution. You wrap the entire thing in a subselect, then `ORDER BY` the first field (Table1ID).

Answer (score 1):

this is one way to do it.

```
select table1.id, table1.type, ifnull(table2.title, table3.title)
from table1
left join table2 on table1.id = table2.table1ID
left join table3 on table1.id = table3.table1ID
```

Comment: Hmm.  This doesn't quite capture the exclusive either-or nature of the question: just add `and table2.table1ID IS NULL` to the end.

Comment: thanks, this works. However, it returns one too many results as the first result is NULL and it's for non-existing table1.id = 1. My first entry in table1 currently has ID of 5

Comment: Actually, if I select table1.* I don't get that empty result. Only getting it when selecting table1.id